# Realm: How to fix 'Invalid property name' RLMException during migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My iOS app uses RealmSwift, and it is crashing during migration from an older version of the app. The error is: `RLMException: Invalid Property Name <name> for class <class>`.

The crash seems to be happening because of the following sequence of migrations:

Initial: Created a model (lets call it Story)

```
class Story: Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic var _id = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastModified: Date?
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var content = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return ServerKey.id
    }

    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["name"]
    }
}
```

Migration X: Created another model using migration.create (lets call it Book) which contains the model created in the previous step (Book contains Story)

```
private class func migrateToVersionX(_ migration: Migration) {
    migration.enumerateObjects( <perform unrelated migration to change some values on story objects> )
    migration.create("Book", value: ["stories": <array containing stories>])
}
```

Migration X+2: Added a new field to Story (Story.author)

```
class Story: Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic var _id = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastModified: Date?
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var content = ""
    @objc dynamic var author = ""


    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return ServerKey.id
    }

    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["name", "author"]
    }
}
```

When a user has a version older than MigrationX, the app crashes with the following error (modified for this example)

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid property name 'author' for class 'Story'.'
```

The app crashes at the `migration.create` call. This is the stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: RLMException
Invalid property name 'author' for class 'Story'.
0   CoreFoundation  
__exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_exception_throw
2   Realm   
RLMAccessor.mm line 567
RLMDynamicGetByName
3   RealmSwift  
Object.swift line 362
DynamicObject.subscript.getter
4   RealmSwift  
<compiler-generated> line 0
@objc DynamicObject.value(forUndefinedKey:)
5   Foundation  
-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:]
6   Realm   
RLMObjectBase.mm line 174
-[RLMObjectBase valueForKey:]
7   Realm   
RLMObjectBase.mm line 451
RLMValidatedValueForProperty
8   Realm   
RLMAccessor.mm line 633
RLMAccessorContext::propertyValue(objc_object*, unsigned long,         RLMProperty*)
9   Realm   
RLMAccessor.mm line 776
RLMAccessorContext::value_for_property(objc_object*,     
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long)
10  Realm   
object_accessor.hpp line 267
realm::Object realm::Object::create<objc_object* __strong,     RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm>     const&, realm::ObjectSchema const&, objc_object* __strong, bool,     realm::BasicRow<realm::Table>*)
11  Realm   
row.hpp line 759
RLMCreateObjectInRealmWithValue
12  Realm   
RLMAccessor.mm line 752
realm::BasicRowExpr<realm::Table>     RLMAccessorContext::unbox<realm::BasicRowExpr<realm::Table> >(objc_object*, bool, bool)
13  Realm   
list.hpp line 192
auto realm::List::dispatch<void realm::List::add<objc_object* __strong&, RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, objc_object* __strong&&&, bool)::'lambda'(objc_object* __strong&)>(objc_object* __strong&&&) const
14  Realm   
RLMAccessor.hpp line 77
void RLMAccessorContext::enumerate_list<void     realm::List::assign<objc_object* __strong&, RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, objc_object* __strong&&&, bool)::'lambda'(objc_object* __strong&&&)>(objc_object*, objc_object* __strong&&&)
15  Realm   
list.hpp line 220
void realm::List::assign<objc_object* __strong&, RLMAccessorContext> (RLMAccessorContext&, objc_object* __strong&&&, bool)
16  Realm   
object_accessor.hpp line 94
void realm::Object::set_property_value_impl<objc_object* __strong,     RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, realm::Property const&,     objc_object* __strong, bool, bool)
17  Realm   
object_accessor.hpp line 281
realm::Object realm::Object::create<objc_object* __strong,     RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm> const&, realm::ObjectSchema const&, objc_object* __strong, bool, realm::BasicRow<realm::Table>*)
18  Realm   
row.hpp line 759
RLMCreateObjectInRealmWithValue
19  Realm   
RLMRealm.mm line 840
-[RLMRealm createObject:withValue:]
20  Realm   
RLMMigration.mm line 135
-[RLMMigration createObject:withValue:]
21  RealmSwift  
Migration.swift line 129
Migration.create(_:value:)
22  Project Name    
MigrationHelper.swift line 187
specialized static MigrationHelper.migrateToVersionX(_:)
```

I think what is happening is that the migration.create function in MigrationX is looking at the Story class and finding the author field, even though it formally isn't introduced until MigrationX+2.

Any thoughts on why this crash is happening and how to appropriately handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general, when a property is *added* to a Realm object, a migration is not needed, unless you want to pre-populate that property.  [Additive changes](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/syncing-data#additive-changes), *such as adding a class or adding a field to a class, are applied automatically*. It's really not clear what's happening but it does seem there is more to this than just adding a property to a class as there's an entirely different object involved (Book) which is not outlined in the question. Perhaps you're trying to modify the Book object (a change, not an add)?

Comment: By the way, you've tagged your question with the realm-mobile-platform so the assumption is you using a mobile sync'd realm. If that's the case, check out the docs for [Destructive Changes](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/syncing-data#destructive-changes) as if you are changing the property of your Book object, that's destructive. If you're not using sync'd Realm, please fix the tag and update the question with what you are using.

Comment: Thank you @Jay. The issue was that `<array containing stories>` being passed into `migration.create` in the second code block above was constructed with the `oldObject` from `migration.enumeration` instead of the `newObject`. `oldObject` does not contain the "author" field, whereas `newObject` does.